# Visual Basic Registry hex conversion output issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, registry

I am trying to build an app in Visual Basic 2012 that will read multiple values and it's data from a registry key and convert from hex to ascii and then output to a list box.

i.e "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RecentDocs" will have multiple entries of any recent files.

The issue I am having is that every time the code runs it can read the data fine and I believe it is converting from hex to ascii ok but it will only output the first letter of each hex conversion.

Here is the code

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.Status

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) andles MyBase.Load
        Dim regkeyRunMRU As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RecentDocs", False)
        Dim w As Object = regkeyRunMRU.GetValueNames()
        For Each s In w
            If s <> "MRUList" Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add(GetREG_BINARY(regkeyRunMRU.ToString, s))
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Function GetREG_BINARY(ByVal Path As String, ByVal Value As String) As String

        Dim Data() As Byte = CType(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(Path, Value, Nothing), Byte())
        If Data Is Nothing Then Return "N/A"
        Dim Result As String = String.Empty
        For j As Integer = 0 To Data.Count - 1
            Result &= Hex(Data(j)).PadLeft(2, "0"c) & " "
        Next

        Dim sResult = Result.Replace(" ", "")
        Dim strTemp As String
        Dim strReturn As String
        Dim I As Long
        For I = 1 To Len(sResult) Step 2
            strTemp = Chr(Val("&H" & Mid$(sResult, I, 2)))
            strReturn = strReturn & strTemp
        Next I
        Return strReturn
    End Function


End Class
```